# Did God look around for help in Isaiah 63:5?

Tags: isaiah

Isaiah 63:5 NASB

> I looked, and there was no one to help, and I was astonished and there was no one to uphold; so My own arm brought salvation to Me, and My wrath upheld Me.

Is God looking around for mankind to help Him, or is this referring to something else? The word “uphold” here particularly confuses me.

Answer (score 2):

To answer to the first part it may be seen as though God looks around and nobody else can accomplish or aid God in what He desires to do, not that God *actually* needs help.

Such a statement can be used as a contrast within Biblical Hebrew (likely Hebrew poetry) that since nobody can help, God then can be contrasted from created beings as the One who will preform the act Himself and bring salvation. Without the contrast, God cannot be seen as the **only** savior.

The word **uphold** on the other hand can mean:

**one assisted**;
סוֹמֵ֑ךְ (sō·w·mêḵ)
Verb - Qal - Participle - masculine singular
Strong's 5564: To prop, to lean upon, take hold of **(1)**

The NET translates this more clearly:

> “I looked, but there was no one to help; I was shocked because there
> *was no one offering support.* So my right arm accomplished deliverance;
> my raging anger drove me on.” ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭63‬:‭5‬ ‭**NET**‬‬

Source:

**(1)** https://biblehub.com/isaiah/63-5.htm#lexicon

Comment: Good answer. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Isaiah alluded to the two comings of the Messiah.
The first coming is found in (ESV) Isaiah 59:

> 15b The LORD saw it, and it displeased him
> that there was no justice.
> 16He saw that there was no man,
> and wondered that there was no one to intercede [H6293];
> then his own arm brought him salvation,
> and his **righteousness** upheld [H5564] him.

H5564 means to sustain or assist.
The righteousness of Jesus' first coming upholds/assists the LORD.

The second coming is found 4 chapters later in Isaiah 63:

> 4For the day of vengeance was in my heart,

i.e., the second coming of vengeance

> and my year of redemption had come.

i.e., the first coming of redemption

> 5 I looked, but there was no one to help;
> I was appalled, but there was no one to uphold [H5564];

Again, no human beings can intercede or assist.

> so my own arm brought me salvation,
> and my **wrath** upheld [H5564] me.

The wrath of the second coming upholds/sustains the LORD. By his fury, God will destroy his foes, the wicked.